# How to send a manual POST request of which I have a file with data?

Tags: php, http, curl, post, http-post

we're using a custom built cart system and during high loads our payment system (Worldpay) times out.

When this happen we receive an email containing the POST request that failed, and this is a .txt file done like the following:

```
   POST /index.php?xxx=yyy&zzz=xxx HTTP/1.0
   Content-Length: 917
   Host: ourdomain.com
   Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
   User-Agent: WJHRO/1.0 (WorldPay Java HTTP Request Object)

   parameter1=value&parameter2=value2
```

How can I actually quickly resend this request to my server so it can register the payment now that the load is more normal? I have this in a .txt file, is there a quick way to do it using this file as it is? Curl? Browsers? In a way so I can see the response to check that all is ok.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the needs you have exposed, it is likely that tools such as [POSTMAN](https://www.getpostman.com/) could help you, allow you to send http requests through an intuitive interface, you can use the various parameters, that are sent to you in the file you mentioned and run the same request check for any errors.

Comment: Ok I will try, it just looked to me very complicated but will give it a try